# need javascript or jquery function to wrap php code (window.setInterval bootstrap list group)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, refresh

Thanks for all the answers, seems like AJAX is the solution, I'll give it a try. But what about JSON? Isn't JSON an even better solution? If it is, why is AJAX more preferable?

I'm looking for a way to update this part of php code every 5 seconds, which would regenerate this bootstrap list group. what would be a good way to do it? I figure I couldn't just wrap it in window.setInterval, and refreshing the entire page is not an option. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    // Display all room
    foreach ($rooms as $room) {
        $room_num = $room['room_num'];
        $room_type = $room['room_type'];
        $note = $room['note'];

        echo '
        <a class="list-group-item" >
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" id="room_num' .$i. '" ><p>'.$room_num." - " .$room_type.'</p></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text" id="note' .$i. '" ><p>'.$note.'</p></p>
        </a>
        ';
        $i++;
    }
    $rooms = "";
    getList();
?>
```

Comment: use ajax/jquery for refresh this part only in 5 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All on the same 'page.php'

php part:

```
<?
if ($_POST["whatever"])
{
echo 'your shizzle here'
exit;
}
?>
```

Javascript part: (with jquery)

```
<script>
setInterval(function()
{
$.post( "page.php", { whatever: 1}, function( data ) {
document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML = data;
});
},5000);
</script>
```

html part

```
<div id = "someid"></div>
```

Another way to do it could be using an iframe :) But iframes won't be used in the future I think.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you write php code inside javascript, it always run once, when the page is loaded. After this you just writing php code to the browser which is simply do not understand (Php is processed on the server, and the output is Html, Css, and Javascript, which the browser can interpret)

So, if you need to update data from the server without reloading the page, the only way to do this is with Ajax Requests, that basically connect to the server within the page and get data from it.

In your case, Save the PHP code which ever you want to execute in a file say `php_temp.php`

Now just do

```
setInterval(function(){
$.get("php_temp.php", function(data){
  console.log(data)  // data stores whatever php_temp.php echoes 
});
},5000);
```

more on Ajax: [Ajax Basics](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)